# selenium move mouse don't work with low resolution

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to use selenium to control chrome browser. 
In my work, i will move in a map, but selenium will work well ,when my screen resolution is 1920*1080, and it doesn't work when my screen resolution is 1366*768.
 the code is that:

```
ChromeDriver driver =(ChromeDriver)webDriver;
    WebElement map =driver.findElementsByClassName("ol-unselectable").get(0); // a MAP
    Actions actions =new Actions(driver);
    System.out.println(map.getSize());
    int x =map.getSize().width;
    int y =map.getSize().height;
    actions.moveToElement(map,0,0).perform();
    actions.moveByOffset(5,5).click().perform();
    actions.moveByOffset((int)(x*0.5),0).click().perform();
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).perform();
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).perform();
    actions.sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.DOWN).perform();
    actions.moveToElement(map,(int)(x*0.5),(int)(y*0.8)).click().perform();
    actions.doubleClick().perform();
```

the code

```
actions.moveToElement(map,(int)(x*0.5),(int)(y*0.8)).click().perform();"
```

doesn't work when I use a low resolution.

the MAP looks like this:[image]
when my Screen Resolution is： **1920*1080**， my Code running result looks like this:[image]
when I change my Screen Resolution to **1366*768**, my Code running result looks like this:[image]
So,we can find that,action can't move to the map element{0.5 width, 0.9 high}.
How should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Few points required sometimes with Actions class:

1. Your element should be present on DOM, if it not how mouse hover would work? (To overcome it. Use scroll up or donw according to the position of the element)
2. If more than one actions you are performing then use build().perform(); not only .perform().
3. Sometimes we can use JavaScript focus method to focus on element before doing any actions using Actions class like below code:

   ```
               JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) ts.getDriver();
               js.executeScript("arguments[0].focus();", we);
               actions.moveToElement(map,(int)(x*0.5),(int)(y*0.8)).click().build().perform();
   ```

Comment: it does work， the map is present on DOM always ,and my code will work when my Screen Resolution is  1920*1080.  my code doesn't work ,when i change my Screen Resolution to 1366*768.  by your code  can't solve the problem.

Comment: map is also present on screen when the resolution is 1920*1080?

Comment: Yes! ,the map always on he screen, No matter how big the resolution is！ the high about the map div  always is 735px

Comment: Then Please check the locator is it also same?

Comment: locator is the sane

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
actions builder = new Actions(driver);   
builder.moveToElement(map,(int)(x*0.5),(int)(y*0.8)).click().build().perform();
```

Maybe that will solve your problem
Sorry i can not just comment under your question ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
actions builder = new Actions(driver);
```

builder.moveToElement(map,(int)(x*0.5),(int)(y*0.8)).click().build().perform();

> please try it. if i am not wrong, it will solve the issue.